# How to create stateless functional components that accept generics?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript generics can used to extend interfaces.

```
interface Sample1<P> {
  prop1: P;
}

interface Sample2<P> extends Sample1<P> {
  prop2: string;
}
```

But when I try to create a functional component that uses the generic interface, typescript throws error.

```
const SampleSFC: React.SFC<Sample2<P>> = () => <div />;
```

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'P'.

If I replace `P` with a known type like `string` the error goes away.

```
const SampleSFC: React.SFC<Sample2<string>> = () => <div />;
```

Instead of hard coding type of `P`, that totally kills the purpose of generics, I want to enable users of `SampleSFC` to set type of `P`.

How can I do that? If it's not possible then what alternate design I should follow that would let me have SFC with generic props.

Comment: Im not sure where your `React.SFC` is located but if this is inside a function you can use this syntax: `function SampleStateless<T>`. Instead of passing `P` or `string` to your `Sample` interface you pass `T`.

Comment: Thank you @Siggy. It is not inside a function. How will other components that want to use SFC access it through a function? Can you please share an example?

Comment: I've tried to do some kind of type assignment to the `SampleSFC<T>` but since it is a react component it's not possible with the standard syntax `SampleSFC<string>()` since this component will be inside the JSX code. I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to use a react component with a generic type since you can't declare the type on the caller side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generic type variables can be used in function and type *declarations* like your interfaces `Sample1` and `Sample2`.
But when you actually *use/call/invoke* generic types, you have to specify a *concrete* type argument instead of `P`.

`React.SFC` - the stateless function component type - is an interface declaration, so using it in an `const` assignment requires a concrete type for `P`.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to make the `SFC` look like a `function` type for the ts-compiler, since function declarations/expressions can 
be assigned generic type parameters. See [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)  for some examples.

### Generic SFC declaration

Leave out the `React.SFC` type annotation to your assignment `const SampleSFC`:

```
const SampleSFC = <P extends {}>(props: Sample2<P>) => <div>{props.prop1} </div>;
```

> Note: The `<P extends {}>` part is needed due to JSX/TSX compatibility
>   issues with generics, see the end of this post.

This way, your component remains a plain function. If you need the additional members from `React.SFC`, add them to your props. E.g. if `children` needed:

```
const SampleSFC = <P extends {}>(props: Sample2<P> & { children?: ReactNode })
 => <div >{props.prop1} </div>;
```

### Generic SFC usage

Since [Typescript 2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements), the type parameter can be directly set in JSX.

```
const MyApp: React.SFC<{}> = (props) => {
    return <SampleSFC<number> prop2="myString" prop1={1} /> 
}
```

### Alternatives

1.) A switch to class components would be easy, if you don't like the quirks.

```
class SampleSFCClass<P> extends React.Component<Sample2<P>> {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.prop1}</div>
    }
}

const MyApp2: React.SFC<{}> = (props) => {
    return <SampleSFCClass<number> prop2="myString" prop1={1} /> 
}
```

2.) You could even wrap the `SFC` in another function.

```
const withGeneric: <P>() => React.SFC<Sample2<P>> = <P extends {}>() => {
    return (props) => <div> {props.prop1}  {props.prop2} </div>;
}

const SampleSFCCalled: React.SFC<Sample2<string>> = withGeneric<string>();

const MyApp: React.SFC<{}> = (props) => {
        return <SampleSFCCalled prop2="myString" prop1="aString" />
}
```

It will work, but disadvantage might be slight performance decrease, because the `SFC` funtion is always recreated in each render cycle of the parent comp.

### JSX/TSX compatibility issues with Generics:

In some constellations Typescript seems to have problems parsing generics in combination with JSX/TSX (up to most recent 3.0.1) due to ambiguous syntax. Compile error will then be:

> "JSX element has no corresponding closing tag."

One of the contributors recommended to use the `function` syntax in this case (see [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15713)).

When you stick to arrow function, workaround is to let the type parameter extend from object (shown [here](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb) or [here](https://dev.to/danhomola/react-higher-order-components-in-typescript-made-simple)) to clarify its meant to be a generic lambda and not a JSX tag:

`<P extends {}>` or `<P extends object>`

Hope, that helps.

Comment: Any function can be generic. You place the type parameter on the value like :`<T>(x: T) =>`

Comment: thanks @AluanHaddad. Adjusted my answer a bit and included the arrow and function style

Answer (score 1):

Generics only work within generic types. So when you are declaring a type `interface Sample1<P>`, then you can use `P` as a type within that declaration. However, the concrete type `Sample1<P>` does not actually exist. Instead `P` is a placeholder for a type when the `Sample1` type is being used.

So using `Sample1<P>` outside of a generic type definition that **also** has a generic type argument `P` does not really work. You can only use actual non-generic types `P` then.

That’s why `Sample1<string>` works, because `string` is a valid value for the type argument `P` in the `Sample1<P>` definition.

If you want so have a `SampleSFC` that works for any type `P`, then you could create it as a `React.SFC<Sample1<any>>`:

```
const SampleSFC: React.SFC<Sample1<any>> = () => <div />;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface MyComponentProps<T> {
  value?: T;
}

export const MyComponent = <T,>(
  props: React.PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps<T>>,
) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {props.children}
      <Text>{(props.value as unknown) as string}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

then in the render method..

```
return (
<MyComponent<string> />
)
```